# Node express async file read

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the below code which is reading a large XML file approx 600mb in size and returns the following output:

```
Total Number of Lines in File: 12077214
Read in 3774.015ms
```

CODE:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require("fs");
var es = require("event-stream");
var now = require("performance-now");

router.get("/testapi", function (req, res, next) {
  var totalLines = 0;
  var t0 = now();
  var t1;

  fs.createReadStream("./large_xml_test.xml")
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(
      es
        .mapSync(function (line) {
          if (line != "") {
            totalLines++;
          }
        })
        .on("error", function (err) {
          console.log("Error while reading file.", err);
        })
        .on("end", function () {
          console.log("Read entire file.");
          t1 = now();
          console.log("Total Number of lines: ", totalLines);

          console.log(
            `Performance now line count timing: ` + (t1 - t0).toFixed(3) + `ms`
          );
          res.send(
            `Total Number of Lines in File: ${totalLines.toString()}<br/>Read in ${(
              t1 - t0
            ).toFixed(3)}ms`
          );
        })
    );
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried moving this to a separate function with using the async and awaits keyword but the results are not displayed when using res.send ie the API is called but a 200 is returned immediately and the await was not happening?

it seems the console log functions fire in vs code only but that's it, is there a way to have this function moved to a separate file and have the res.send await the return value?

Thanks just learning nodejs currently.

=================== EDIT ===================

In answer to Keiths statement this was the last item I tested but failed with:

FILE 1:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const test = require("../functions/readFileEventStream");

router.get("/testapi", function (req, res, next) {
  let message = "API is working properly";
  const results = (async function () {
    await test.readLargeFile();
  })();
  res.send(results);
});

module.exports = router;
```

File 2

```
var fs = require("fs");
var es = require("event-stream");
var now = require("performance-now");

var totalLines = 0;
var t0 = now();
var t1;

async function readLargeFile() {
  fs.createReadStream("./large_xml_test.xml")
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(
      es
        .mapSync(function (line) {
          if (line != "") {
            totalLines++;
          }
        })
        .on("error", function (err) {
          console.log("Error while reading file.", err);
        })
        .on("end", function () {
          t1 = now();
          var msg = `Total Number of Lines in File: ${totalLines.toString()},\r\nRead in ${(
            t1 - t0
          ).toFixed(3)}ms`;
          return msg;
        })
    );
}

module.exports = {
  readLargeFile,
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can just wrap this logic into a Promise constructor, you can then await this in your route.  It might be best if you show the code were you tried to split, and then we can explain how to fix.

Comment: @Keith i have added the test code I tried there were other attempts but I overwrote them this being the last one.

Comment: Look at Edwards answer, it shows you how to convert event based callbacks into a Promise constructor, that you can then later await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic that reads the file can be encapsulated into a Promise. Why a Promise?
The Promise is supported by await mechanism so it can be awaited in an async function. Usually in a Promise is placed code that is not synchronous so the mapSync is changed to map so the file can be processed asynchronously.

```
router.get("/testapi", async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let t0 = now();
        let totalLines = await readFile('./large_xml_test.xml');
        console.log("Read entire file.");
        let t1 = now();
        console.log("Total Number of lines: ", totalLines);

        console.log(
            `Performance now line count timing: ` + (t1 - t0).toFixed(3) + `ms`
        );
                        
        res.send(
            `Total Number of Lines in File: ${totalLines.toString()}<br/>Read in ${(
                t1 - t0
            ).toFixed(3)}ms`
        );
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('error reading file ' + err);
        res.status(500).send('failed to read file');
    }
});

function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let totalLines = 0;
        fs.createReadStream(path)
            .pipe(es.split())
            .pipe(
                es.map(function (line, cb) {
                    if (line != "") {
                        totalLines++;
                    }

                    cb(null);
                })
                    .on("error", function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    })
                    .on("end", function () {
                        
                        resolve(totalLines);
                    })
            );
    })
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for this, this actually has taught me a lot in regards to the async structure that I was clearly misunderstanding and the fact that the promise system is the way forward which I was missing; also thanks for pointing out that the mapSync function is deprecated. Really appreciate the time and effort taken to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind here is that your XML reader and your route handler are *both* event-driven functions.  In your example you call `res.send()` from *inside* your `on("end"...)` event handler. That's why things wait the way you want.

The easiest way to split up the XML reader and the route handler is to make them both `async`.    This code is examples, and is not debugged.

Route handler

```
router.get("/testapi", async function (req, res, next) {

  var t0 = now();
  var t1;

  var totalLines = await getXML ("./large_xml_test.xml"); 

  console.log("Read entire file.");
  t1 = now();
  console.log( whatever );
  res.send( whatever );
} )
```

Your xml reader module

```
var fs = require("fs");
var es = require("event-stream");

async function getXML (file)
  let totalLines = 0
  fs.createReadStream(file)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(
      es
        .mapSync(function (line) {
          if (line != "") {
            totalLines++;
          }
        })
        .on("error", function (err) {
          throw new Error ("Error while reading file.", err);
        })
        .on("end", function () {
           return totalLines;
        })
     );
});

module.exports = getXML;
```

The trick is this.  `async getXML` doesn't return until it completes and hits its `on("end"...) event handler. And so your route handler doesn't call` res.send()` until your xml loading operation is done.

Comment: @EduardHasanaj's solution is also good. In mine I used `async` rather than an explicit Promise, but they're pretty much equivalent solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately there not the same, and this will fail.  This will just return a Promise that returns undefined.